# I can't remove python 3.9.6 from my macOs

Tags: python-3.x, pyenv

I was using python versions 3.9.6 and 3.9.9 which I installed outside of pyenv. Using pyenv I installed 3.10. When I run the command `pyenv versions` the only version listed is 3.10 as shown below:

[image]

I manually deleted python 3.9.9 from my macOS "applications" folder, so the only version I should have on my macOS is 3.10. But when I run `python3 --version` I get this:

[image]

when I run the command which python3:

[image]

I would like to know how to remove Python version 3.9.6 on my macOS. I opened the folder where this version of Python is and when I tried to delete it I got the following message.

[image]

the same thing happened when I tried with "sudo" to delete the file from the terminal.

I would like to use python versions with pyenv, but I am having trouble getting the Python version to default to 3.9.6 on my MacOS. Can someone help me remove this version of Python from my system?

Comment: did you check your Applications folder? See: https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-uninstall-python

Comment: is that your system python? You shouldn't delete that if so. But what does `ls -la $(which python3)` give you?

Comment: Don't worry about the system's python. Run `pyenv global 3.10.0`, it will set your global python interpreter to 3.10 and ignore the system's python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
return this:
 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167136 Oct 28 05:43 /usr/bin/python3

Comment: @blurfus yes, in the applications folder there is only pyenv version 3.10.

Comment: @FanchenBao so I can literally not worry about this python 3.9.6 file?

Comment: It doesn't have a `->` after that pointing somewhere else? Cna you provide the full output in the question itself as formatted text

Comment: What does `readlink -f /usr/local/bin/python3` do?

Comment: @Louis why *are* you worried about this? I suspect it is the system Python, which you shouldn't delete (because it is used by your operating system). But even if it isn't, I see no reason to worry.

Comment: @Louis That is correct. No need to worry about the python 3.9.6 files, because they are used by the system, and you will not touch them once you point to a different python interpreter via `pyenv`. On my machine, I have so many python versions from the system and homebrew. It's a mess, but `pyenv` ensures that you will only interact with the python you ask for. Commands like `pyenv global`, `pyenv virtualenv`, and `pyenv local` are super helpful to control the madness of python environment.